# Как правильно организовать таблицы в БД для функции Share (pin it), т.е. добавления предметов?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом лучше организовать функцию  расшаривание сущностей (продуктов, картинок) в проекте, если в перспективе проект возможно будет расти на несколько физических серверов.

То есть, допустим, есть сущность `Предметы` (картинки, товары). Каждый пользователь может добавлять предметы (например взяв их у других пользователей) себе, но он может менять все параметры кроме изображения.

1. Первый вариант это две таблицы: `Изображения` и `Предметы`. Таблица `Предметы` хранит все свойства и `id` на изображение в предметах. Таблица изображений хранит все картинки, добавленные в систему.
2. Либо сделать одну избыточную таблицу, где будет дублирование ссылок на изображение?

Либо другой Ваш вариант.

Comment: @Танюша Старолатко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
//items:
ID, IMG

//users:
ID, Nickname

//owners:
User_id, item_id, property1, property2, property3....
```

Есть глобальный "юзер" - склад. Storage. В юзерах он имеет ID=0. Там для каждого предмета указаны дефолтные значения.

Если свойства совсем разные, то создается еще одна таблица

```
propertes:
item_id, property, value,
```

А в таблица owners начинает выглядеть так:

```
//owners:
User_id, item_id....
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. А такой вариант построения таблиц будет нормально расширяться в будущем?

Comment: Особенно, последний вариант.

Comment: А если вариант, что в будет несколько серверов, и тогда пользователь делает запрос к нескольким серверам, т.к. не понятно где (на каком из серваков) будет храниться ссылка на картинку. Поясните, плиз, чуть подробнее о масштабировании в этом случае?

Comment: Если серваки вообще никак не связаны, придется последовательно их опрашивать.
Чаще всего, сервера связаны, поэтому сквозной запрос идет как к одному серверу.
Еще вариант - создать индекс, но это при очень большом числе серверов.

И еще. Базовые элементы лежат на всех серверах. Остальные - распределены. В таком случае, даже при очень большом числе пользователей мы всегда сможем найти источник картинки, сделав всего два запроса.